# CSS Selectors issue

Tags: html, css

Class inside class, pseudo selector not working.

```
        <div class="lists">

        <ul style="text-align:right">

        <li>
        <a href="#1">
       HOME
        </a>
        </li>

        <li>
        <a href="#2">
        ABOUT US
        </a>
        </li>

        <li><a href="#3">
        SOLUTIONS</a>
        </li>

        <li><a href="#5">
        CONTACT</a>
        </li>

        </ul>

        </div>
        </div></head>

    <body style="margin:auto;-webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;">
        <center>

        <!-- NEW CONTAINER -->
        <div class="second_c">
        <div class="bg_box">
        <h3>OPTIMIZING LEARNING EXPERIENCE</h3>
        <p style="text-align:center">NAME
        </p></div>
        </div>

        <div class="present">
            <h2 class="team_box">TEAM</h2>  
            <p>
            Our team    
            </p>
        </div>

        <div class="team_member" >
            <ul>
            <li>Team Member 1</li>
            <li>Team Member 2</li>
            </ul>

            <ul>
            <li>Team Member 3</li>
            <li>Team Member 4</li>
            </ul>
        </div>

            <div class="present" >
                <h2 class="team_box" id="2">SOLUTIONS</h2>
                    <div class="grey_box"><p><br>SMART GYAN</p></div>
                    <div class="grey_box"><p>ENTRANCE <br>SOLUTIONS</p></div>
                    <div class="grey_box"><p>DIGI <br> SOLUTIONS</p></div>
            </div>
        </center>
```

I want to select the h2 individually,

CSS:

```
.present:first-child h2
{
    margin-right: 600px; 
    margin-left: 600px;
}

.present:.present:not(:first-child) h2
{
    margin-right: 500px; 
    margin-left: 500px;
}
```

Like i want to give the first h2, different property and the other one different
Tried the answer, but didn't work.

Comment: What selector have you used? Can you use .present:last-child?

Comment: *What* isn't working? The only thing worse than not describing "not working", is not even showing what it is that isn't working.

Comment: ".present:last-child" is working but not the ".present:first-child"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the **nth-child()** property in your CSS. First index is 1.

This will only apply to the first DIV.present (within the parent container):

```
DIV.present:nth-child(1) H2.team_box
{
    ... your style ...
}
```

This will only apply to the second DIV.present (within the parent container):

```
DIV.present:nth-child(2) H2.team_box
{
    ... your style ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks,

but I ended up using this:

 .present:nth-child(2) h2.team_box
{
 margin-right: 600px; 
 margin-left: 600px;
}

 .present:nth-child(4) h2.team_box
{
 margin-right: 500px; 
 margin-left: 500px;
}

Answer (score 0):

You could also use multiple classes within the h2 tag if you wanted a more semantic approach

```
    <div class="present">
        <h2 class="team_box team_box_first">TEAM</h2>  
        <p>Our team</p>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

in first I'm sorry for bad english.

```
<div class="present">
    <h2 class="team_box">TEAM1</h2>  
    <h2 class="team_box">TEAM2</h2>  
</div>

<div class="present">
    <h2 class="team_box">TEAM3</h2>
</div>
```

when you use below code:

```
.present H2.team_box:nth-child(1)
{
    color:green;
}

.present H2.team_box:nth-child(2)
{
    color:red;
}
```

the H2 color with value of TEAM1 and TEAM3 is green. because nth-child(1) is each first item with same class name in each div , not the first H2 in code.

the H2 color with value of TEAM2 is red.

Answer (score -2):

```
     your study click webaddress  

     http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#pattern-matching
     http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#selectors
```

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#pattern-matching
     http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#selectors